# Apply a function to a vector a regular intervals

Tags: r

I have two related questions, first how do I split a vector at regular intervals and apply a function to each interval and second, how would I split a vector into a dataframe at regular intervals where each interval is a row of the dataframe. The first question has been asked before and there appears to be a nifty solution using `rollapply()` in `zoo`, but when I tried to install it, I was informed that `zoo` was not available for R 3.1.1.

I have working solutions, but I don't like that I have to create additional index variables for them to work. Any simpler solutions?

Part 1 Applying a function at a regular interval

```
d <- data.frame(Value=rnorm(1000,100,20),   #create random values
                y=factor(rep(1:100,each=10)), # create a group variable
                t=factor(rep(1:10, 100))) # create an observation # variable numbering
                                          # observation 1-10

data.frame(tapply(d$Value, FUN=mean, INDEX=d$y)) #take mean of observations by group
```

Part 2
Splitting the vector into a dataframe.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data=d, y~t, value.var='Value')
```

---

R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: `zoo` is alive and well, and I've just installed it on the same architecture using `install.packages`. You can also get it from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html

Comment: And here's how you'd use it: `rollapply(d$Value, width=10, by=10, FUN=mean)`. As to your second question, a matrix might be more appropriate if it's all numeric: `m <- matrix(d$Value, byrow=T, ncol=10)`. Wrap in `as.data.frame` as necesary. You can then also achieve your first aim with `rowMeans(m)`.

Comment: ok, I will check zoo again.  That second solution is exactly the simple solution I am looking for!

Comment: Great - have added it as a solution so that the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve your grouped mean is, as you mentioned, to use `zoo::rollapply`. This can be done as follows:

```
rollapply(d$Value, width=10, by=10, FUN=mean)
```

Alternatively, convert `d$value` to a `matrix` (or `data.frame`, though the former is typically more efficient and often more appropriate when all columns are of a consistent mode, e.g. numeric), and calculate row means. For example:

```
m <- matrix(d$value, byrow=TRUE, ncol=10)
rowMeans(m)
```

Or, for any given function `f`:

```
apply(m, 1, f)
```